# Is there another way to plot a graph in python without matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

As the title says, that's basically it. I have tried to install matplotlib already but:

1. I am on Windows and "sudo" doesn't work
2. Every solution and answers on Stack Overflow regarding matplotlib (or some other package) not being able to be installed doesn't work for me...
3. I get "Error Code 1"

So! Is there any other way to plot a graph in python without matplotlib? If not, can I have help with how to install matplotlib, successfully?

Comment: sudo shouldn't have to work. If you're on windows, have you tried installing directly using pip? Matplotlib is cross-platform and should run wherever Python does.

If you did use pip, do you get a certain error?

Comment: There are other plotting libraries of course https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting However installing matplotlib is pretty easy. Make sure to have python installed, then `python -mpip install matplotlib` installs matplotlib.

Comment: @anerisgreat Yes I get error code 1

Comment: On Windows you can try python distribution with matplotlib, https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/installing.html#scientific-python-distributions

Comment: @graphite none of them worked for me

Comment: Have tried installing matplotlib using **"PIP"** in Windows?

Answer (score -1):

You have another one option install seaborn library and plot the graph.

If you want plot a normal graph means you can directly use plot function to plot graph like data.plot.bar\pie\hist\line like this...

Comment: Seaborn depends on matplotlib

Answer (score -3):

in cmd (coammand prompt) type pip install matplotlib

Comment: he literally said "without matplotlib"